# Want to refresh page one time on particular URL hit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to refresh the page only one time when a particular URL is hit.

The reason for this is to refresh the data on the view. My URL is

```
http://localhost:8072/web?#min=1&limit=80&view_type=list&model=pos.order&action=405
```

And solutions I have tried are

```js
window.onload = function() {
    //considering there aren't any hashes in the urls already
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        //setting window location
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        //using reload() method to reload web page
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

```js
(function()
{
  if( window.localStorage )
  {
    //check if reloaded once already 
    if( !localStorage.getItem('firstLoad') )
    {
     //if not reloaded once, then set firstload to true
      localStorage = true;
      //reload the webpage using reload() method
      window.location.reload();
    }  
    else 
      localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
  }
})();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
    //Check if the current URL contains '# or hash'
    if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1){
        // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#loaded".
        url = document.URL+"#loaded";
        location = "#loaded";
        //Reload the page using reload() method
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

None of them worked for me. What is wrong or which direction should I choose?

Comment: `localStorage = true;` is trying to overwrite global `localStorage` object, not setting a key/value  in storage. Your mix of `?#` in url is strange also

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution works fine, it just needed a return statement to prevent execution the rest of the code, however if your original url contains a hash, you can do the check like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("test").textContent = window.location;
  console.log(window.location.hash);
  //check for our specific hash argument
  if (!window.location.hash.match(/[#&]loaded(&|$)/)) {
    alert("the page is about to refresh");
    //setting window location
    window.location = window.location + (window.location.hash ? "&" : "#") + 'loaded';
    //using reload() method to reload web page
    window.location.reload();
    return;
  }
  alert("page refreshed");
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: There is a hash in my case.

Comment: Than I'd need more about your code and how exactly it's "not working". As you can see here it's working fine.

Comment: Can you start a private room?